# What is ROS path (e.g. ~/ros)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is meant when you are told to move into your personal ROS path (e.g. ~/ros)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12535/what-is-ros-path-(e.g.-%7E/ros)./) by [atslagle](https://answers.ros.org/users/1611/atslagle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-01-05

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-01-24**:
Please post with enough information for us to reproduce your setup.  Or what instructions you are following.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depends on the context. There is `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`, used to resolve packages, and `$ROS_HOME` which is usually the current directory when running `roslaunch` (and defaults to `~/.ros`).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-01-05**:
Are you sourcing your setup.sh correctly?

**Comment by [atslagle](https://answers.ros.org/users/1611/atslagle/) on 2012-01-05**:
So when I run this, rosmake --rosdep-install pi_speech_tutorial, I get an error saying that it Rospack failed to build do you know what I am doing wrong?